# Using iloc in python with function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign the correct FinalZone from df5 to df7.

df7 :

```
 OrigZone    DestZone    FinalZone
 5           6           (output should be 9)
 8           5           (output should be 2)
```

df5 (FinalZone lookup table) :

```
  Zip3 1  2  3  4  5  6
     5 7  2  3  5  8  9
     6 3  1  5  8  8  8
     7 3  3  8  8  9  1
     8 5  5  6  6  2  2

def zone_assign(row):
    return df5.iloc[df5.loc[df5['ZIP3']==row['OrigZone']].index,row['DestZone']] 

df7.apply(zone_assign, axis=1)
```

When I ran this, I got a printout of my df5 with a bunch of `NaN` in it. I am so lost.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions folks. Can someone tell me why my original method did not work?

Comment: How to get the original method to work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `lookup` here

```
#df5=(df5.set_index('Zip3'))
#df5.columns=df5.columns.astype(int)

df7['FinalZone']=df5.lookup(df7.OrigZone,df7.DestZone) 

df7
Out[130]: 
   OrigZone  DestZone  FinalZone
0         5         6          9
1         8         5          2
```

Comment: Wen, this is awesome. I cannot find anything on the internet describing the lookup function. Can you tell me how to fix my original code? Thanks.

Comment: @MSanders change to `df7.apply(zone_assign, axis=1).sum(1)`

Comment: Wen, why did I need to this. Also, where is this lookup() function from. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @MSanders https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html

Comment: What is the sum(1) doing?

Comment: @MSanders did you check what is your output ? row['DestZone'] this will return [6,5] , which means when you are doing the apply , you always check both 6 and 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168676/discussion-between-m-sanders-and-wen).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, assuming your `df5` columns are integers.

```
df7['FinalZone'] = df7.apply(lambda x: df5.loc[x['OrigZone'], x['DestZone']], axis=1)

print(df7)

#    OrigZone  DestZone  FinalZone
# 0         5         6          9
# 1         8         5          2
```